# loadNibNamed() fails: Unknown class <mangled Swift identifier> in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, nsbundle

I've moved code to an Xcode framework and now a `loadNibNamed()` fails with (I changed the readable parts of the mangled Swift identifier name):

```
Unknown class _TtC13MyFramework14MyTableCell in Interface Builder file.
```

The `loadNibNamed()` is called from a Swift file that has `MyFramework` Target Membership.

The `UITableViewCell` subclass (`MyTableCell`) is an Obj-C class. It's header has `public` `MyFramework` Target Membership, and its `.m` is also member of the framework.  The cell is very simple, having an `UIImageView` and a few `UILabel`s, no custom classes.

In the XIB the table cell's Class has been set to `MyTableCell`.  And, Module to `MyFramework`, with Inherit Module From Target selected.

I've set the Product Bundle Identifier of the framework.  And I get the bundle using:

```
[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.mycompany.myframework"];
```

The bundle is found; checked by printing its `bundlePath`.

I've looked up this issue and have tried all kinds of variations, for example not assigning ``MyTableCell`'s Module, but nothing works.  I've also created a new cell XIB with a Swift class, but with the same result.

Any ideas what I should/could still try?

Comment: I've mostly encountered this `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myImage` error when deleting the IBOutlet from source file and that was still connected to storyboard. So maybe, you have Outlet connection in storyboard with name `myImage`. Please check if it helps

Comment: The `class is not key value coding-compliant` is a side-effect of my subclass not being found. That's not the first/main issue.

Comment: Have you tried creating an instance of `MyTableCell` programmatically to see if there are any more useful error messages?

Comment: @waldrumpus `let cell = MyTableCell()` simply works; just tried it to double check.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out some solution that works for me - YMMV.

So in my situation I needed to expose some custom Swift UIControl subclasses to the Objective C runtime. I did this by adding an annotation as such:

```
@objc(CustomButton)
public class CustomButton: UIButton {
    // some implementation
}
```

When this class was added to a Framework an error appeared, quite similar as yours.

```
Unknown class _TtC9CustomFramework12CustomButton in Interface Builder file.
```

To fix this issue I had to modify my XIB file to remove the module.

[image: Remove Module in XIB]

When adding the framework to another project all works fine now. No errors and the custom views appear as expected.